# Loop in Nunjucks behaving differently depending on inner HTML markup

Tags: javascript, client-side-templating, nunjucks

I have the following Nunjucks template supposed to render a list of items as
list:

```
{% for item in items %}
    <li>
        {{item.title}}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

and as table

```
<table border="1">
  {% for item in items %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{item.title}}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

The list is correctly rendered as

```
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
```

however the table is supposed to have three TR elements however it is rendered as

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
     <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Why is there only one TR element instead of three TR elements?

JSFiddle is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/user0815/r41akt22/5

Comment: The JSFiddle link says 404 We're truly sorry, but there is no such page.

Comment: It seems that `$('#template').html()` does not preserve the `nunjucks` markup and does not return the template #2 that you expect

Answer (score 1):

Same issue, not sure why that happen, but here is my solution:

```
<table id="target" >replace target tag DIV to TABLE</table>
```

And remove useless table tag from your item loop, just wrap it by template tag:

```
<template id="template">
  {% for item in items %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{item.title}}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</template>
```

The table rows will render corrently. I just test with htmx + nunjucks, hope that can help.

Comment: Helpful answer for my problem, even if probably unrelated to the original question. Did you ever figure out why this happens?